# How to start a cage induction motor when load torque is greater than starting torque?

Tags: motor, power-electronics, induction-motor, electrical, electric-machine

How to start a cage induction motor when load torque is greater than starting torque ?

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: There are many ways. But it really doesn't look like you've put any effort into finding out for yourself, so this question isn't appropriate.

Comment: Your question is off to a bad start and may be closed soon. Please update your question to provide the following information: What is the load? What is the make and model of motor? If make and model is not known, what is the output power of the motor (HP or kW)? What is the power source (single or three phase, frequency and voltage)?

Comment: Mechanically use a torque converter.

Comment: Much like when an automatic washing machine kicks into a spin cycle. The load is very large, so a small torque converter is used.

Comment: Sorry friends if the question is not clear. This was asked in my interview for executive electrical engineer position and I was not able to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the motor truly does not have enough starting torque, you probably need a different motor. However, someone apparently already bought one motor that doesn't have enough starting torque, so it would be a good idea to figure out how much starting torque is required.

If the load is driven by a belt or chain and sprockets, you can get more toque by changing the ratio, but that requires reducing the speed.

Depending on the motor and load details there are ways of getting more torque using a variable frequency drive (VFD), but that would be expensive and not worthwhile unless variable speed would be an attractive alternative.

Comments have mentioned using a torque converter. That would probably be less expensing than a VFD depending on power rating, installation costs etc. A torque inverter or a VFD would allow the use of the highest point of the motor's torque vs. speed curve for starting the load.

Comment: A VFD might be able to better UTILIZE the maximum torque available from a motor, because I'm assuming that you were thinking in terms of the VFD being able to more fully take advantage of the Break Down Torque of the motor, as opposed to the Starting Torque (Locked Rotor Torque). BDT is often a slightly higher amount. But the maximum torque that the motor can develop is the maximum torque the VFD can make it develop. If that's not enough, the motor is too small.

Comment: Yes, and these days, VFDs can get pretty close to the breakdown torque.